# Stop loading jquery library from assets folder in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I had problem in my app that made it slow , after checked firebug 
I noted that jquery-ui loaded twice first from google.com and second from assets folder ("232kb") .

How to force it to load from google.com without assets version ?

[image: Firebug screenshot]

View content " JavaScript to call Ajax function ":

```
....
     $(".third,#second-next,#fourth-pr").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/CallScientificForm',array('language'=>language())); ?>',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#loading").show();
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        $("#hr3").css("background", "#51a351");
                        $("*").removeClass("active");
                        $(".third").addClass("active");
                        $("#firstContent ,#secondContent,#thirdContent,#fourthContent").fadeOut(2000);
                        $("#thirdContent").html(data);
                        $("#thirdContent").fadeIn(2000);
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#' + id + ' .contentarea').html(textStatus);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
                    }
                });

            });
...
```

Controller:

```
...
  public function actionCallScientificForm()
    {
        $scienceModel = new MembershipScientific();
        $view= $this->renderPartial('_ScientificForm', array('scienceModel' => $scienceModel, 'language' => language()), false, true);
        echo $view;
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
..
```

Main config:

```
 'clientScript'=>array(
            'packages'=>array(
                'jquery'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.js'),
                    'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_END
                ),
                'jqueryMin'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
                    'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_END
                ),
                'jquery-ui'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
                    'js'=>array('jquery-ui.min.js'),
                    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
                    'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_END
                )
            ),
        ),
```

And I called it in target view like this :

```
....
cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();

$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery-ui');
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set them in `clientScript` to **false** to prevent them from loading.

A few examples of scripts you can disable:

```
'components' => array(
    'clientScript' => array(

        // disable default yii scripts
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery.js'     => false,
            'jquery.min.js' => false,
            'core.css'      => false,
            'styles.css'    => false,
            'pager.css'     => false,
            'default.css'   => false,
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use script map:

```
'clientScript' => [
    'class' => 'CClientScript',
    'scriptMap' => [
         'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js',
         'jquery.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js',
         'jquery-ui.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js',
         'jquery-ui.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js'
    ],
....
```

Also remove jQuery and jQuery ui from packages. This should resolve double registering.

**NOTE:** It is better to use protocol-relative urls: `//example.com/blah/` - this way will work also with `https`

Comment: Forgot about removing 'core' packages, as these double core scripts, updated answer.